# Confusion with python global variables, pygame event

Tags: python, pygame, global-variables

I have read a couple of other questions on the topic, but still I don't seem to get python global variables to work.

I have three files: main.py, menu.py and game.py.

menu.py contains a menu function that is executed by main; main has a 'running' variable for its main loop, and I want the functions in the other files to be able to set it to 0 in order to exit the game.

But I cannot get it to work; for example, if I do this:

menu.py

```
...
class gameMenu():
def __init__(self, screen, background):
    #self.event = event
    global running

...
running = 0
```

main.py

```
...
from menu import *
...
global running
running = 1

title = gameMenu(screen, background)
title.run()
...
print running
```

But, main will always print 1. How can I get menu to modify the running variable in main?

Also, in the menu loop I have this function:

```
for e in pygame.event.get():

         if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            print 'Close!'
            self.isRunning = 0
            running = 0

         if e.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print 'Button Down!'
            self.isRunning = 0
```

This code works fine in another program, but in this one the second if never gets executed, and honestly I do not understand why.

If you need the complete code, it's here: http://dumptext.com/KuwcaWpH

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In `menu.py` how are you importing `running`?

Comment: from menu import *, I thought it would import everything but apparently not.

Comment: It would import everything, but then in your `main.py` when you do  `running = <something>` , you shadowed the variable imported from `menu` , now its a global variable from `main.py` not `menu.py` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are no where importing the global variable `running` from `main.py` into `menu.py` . When you do -

```
if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
   print 'Close!'
   self.isRunning = 0
   running = 0
```

You are just setting a local name (variable) to 0 , this does not affect the `running` variable in `main.py` . You might want to add the following line to the start of the function - `def run(self):`

```
def run(self):
    global running
    self.isRunning = 1
```

Also, seems like you are defining `running = 1` in `main.py` , this can shadow the `running` global variable you want to import from `menu.py` . Try removing that line. Or the best would be to do -

```
import menu
```

Then access the global variable as - `menu.running`

Comment: refer to it as `menu.gameMenu` , refer to everything and anything from `menu` as `menu.<name>`

Answer (score 1):

`Global` variables in Python are actually only within the scope of a single file. The keyword is used to allow local scopes (like functions and loops) to assign values to wider scoped variables.

When going from file to file, importing is what you actually want to use. An import allows you to see variables from another script, not just functions and objects. It allows you to assign to them too. Though these assignments wont affect the script as it's saved on the drive, it can change values like your `running`.

So you could do

```
from menu import running
```

And then check and assign its value. Or if you just used `import menu`, refer to `running` with `menu.running`.